# [clickhouse]- RSS memory keep on growing till 80GB out of 128GB RAM and dropped suddenly once in 24 hours

Tags: clickhouse

I am facing a strange issue where within 24 hours RSS memory reach upto 80 GB of total 128GB RAM, then it dropped suddenly after 20-24 hrs.
Again it start increasing same thing happens daily from last 10 days.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: CH Version?????

Comment: Clickhouse Version is-20.6.3.28 and max peak memory usages shown in log is 300MiB

Comment: upgrade  to 20.6.11.1

Comment: Hi @DennyCrane- Please provide any reference for the cause of issues and incase it is fixed in 20.6.11.1- This will be great help